# Naming convention for auxiliary typescript classes in Angular

Tags: angular, naming-conventions

In angular2 style guide there is a section for [naming](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#naming) files, where it is specified:

> Do follow a pattern that describes the symbol's feature then its type.
> The recommended pattern is `feature.type.ts`.

Let's say we are writing trading platform. So in the same folder we have  directive `trade.directive.js`  that reference simple view `trade.html`. Then we needed to link controller to it: `trade.controller.js`. We had some code that was like helpers – thus extracted it to `trade.helpers.service.js` (common for Ruby on Rails, thus we wouldn't bother about defining `type` part in conventional `feature.type.ts` naming).

But then we’ve seen that we have a complex structure that should be initialized for each trade. Thus we extracted this class to it's own `TradeViewModel.js`. As it was enormous (like 500 lines), we logically extracted some classes from it, put them into separate files like: `TradeGeneralInformation`, `TradeProductABody`, `TradeProductBBody` etc. now we have like 10 files that is used inside service/controller of trade directive to construct data with some methods attached to it. Thus we are able to have small files with classes that can be composed into big structure we need.

Those things are not services, they are more like POJO in Java – they encapsulate some data. Now inside `trade/` folder we have subfolder `viewModels/` with these files.

**But** according to style guide files in angular application should have some suffixes in names e.g. `*.directive.js`.

**Question:** How do you name files with class definitions that are integral parts of Angular application, but doesn't have any Angular objects defined inside?

Or, should we just name them according to the classes they represent and put them in separate folders where they belong logically?

Comment: The question is mostly opinion base and should be closed. I wouldn't introduce "type" names if there isn't one that is common all over the application and clearly makes it easier to understand what the file is about instead of only adding noise. Angular style guide introduces a few and I think it's a good idea to use them, but otherwise I wouldn't without a compelling reason.

Comment: I don't think it is too opinion-based since it is asking for clarification on the angular styleguide, which lays out conventions that most would consider essential for angular development. There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957717/filetype-naming-convention-for-angular-classes