# Filetype Naming Convention for Angular Classes

Tags: angular

Angular's [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#symbols-and-file-names) lists naming conventions for common file types, such as `heroes.component.ts`, or `heroes.service.ts`, etc. But what about classes that have no decorator symbols? For example, the Heroes tutorial creates a Hero class:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

It then names this file `hero.ts`. A naming convention like this seems prone to chaos in the `app` directory. It seems logical to create a folder named classes (in the app directory), and then add a `class.ts` suffix to each file, such as `hero.class.ts`.

However, I have not seen anyone using this convention. I've seen people use a `model.ts` suffix, but it's unclear whether or not this is a best practice, and it is not mentioned in the Angular [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#symbols-and-file-names).

Can anyone shed some light on this topic? Sorry if I've missed anything. Thank you advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular Style Guide explicitly says to use `.model` for simple models. However, you should consider 2 things:

- there is no convention for `enums`. Personally I keep them inside of `service` or `model` file, depending on how it supposed to be used
- guide allows to create other `entities`, so in scope of your project - you can add other "types" (recource, config)
- if class/model/interface (e.g. `User`) is used across application, guide suggests to keep it in `shared` module, which is logically right: `SharedModule` is supposed to be imported multiple times, while `CoreModule` - only once (in `AppModule`)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry but I still don't see it. I mean, I see a section on small functions here https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#small-functions that shows a 'model.ts' file, but I wouldn't call that explicit. I'll go through it again with a fine tooth comb. My bad if it's right in front of my face.

Comment: Search for `Interfaces` section and `Rule of One` (there is example on naming `HeroModel`). Also see `Style 04-06`, `Style 04-10` and `Style 04-11`. `Style 02-02` says that you can add addition types in your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating packages (folders) in your application:

- package by layer
- package by feature

Angular prefers "package by feature" and that's why hero class remains within hero component which it belongs to. Good post about why "package by feature" is preferred way is [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205).

As for classes/services which are used for several components - Angular StyleGuide suggests to use core package. If it's a component which is shared - then a shared package.